# Django application redirecting all urls

Tags: django, django-forms

I made a very simple django application, and just added a form (and related views, entries in urls.py etc), however I noticed no matter what URL I put in the address bar it always just redirects to the homepage.

This is my **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.index, name='index'),
    url('booking/new/', views.booking_new, name='booking_new'),
]
```

and my **views.py**:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .forms import BookingForm

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('/home/dave/dave/dave_site/home/templates/home/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))

def booking_new(request):
    form = BookingForm()
    return render(request, 'home/booking_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

I noticed when attempting to access /home/booking/new or /booking/new that it just loads the default homepage I setup. When putting in any url, even a nonsense one, it still shows this website, and the log to the console from running runserver shows ever request as `HTTP 200 successful`.

I don't seem to have setup a `catchall` url, so not sure why this is happening.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: check this for your first url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

Comment: Your welcome, read docs for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Django url docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/)

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

In url.py change first url to `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')`

Answer (score 2):

An empty string `''` *is* a blanket pattern. You should make it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

It is because it `''` always match with every urls. You have to add regex or move it to the bottom(But if it doesn't match any patterns it will show your index page)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url('booking/new/', views.booking_new, name='booking_new'),
]
```

From Django documents

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request